# TYPO3: Upload files to FAL with powermail

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, fal, powermail

I am using powermail to allow a FE-User to edit a couple of fields of his own User-Record. Works fine, no hassle.

Now I would also like to allow the upload of a file. Is there a way to save the file to FAL with powermail? Unfortunately I have found no resources on this whatsoever. Maybe it is possible to implement a userfunc when saving to DB that would generate the required DB entries? When using powermails "upload"-field-type the file gets written to uploads/tx_powermail. I have access to that files path in my db_entry step in typoscript and could pass it on to a userfunc - which in return should

- generate the sys_file entry
- delete a possiblibly already existing sys_file_reference
- generate the new sys_file_reference

Am I missing something?
Any ideas on this? Has anyone done something like this before?

Or is my only alternative to switch from powermail to a custom extbase extension?

System: TYPO3 7.6.16, Powermail 3.17

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment powermail don't uses FAL relations. If you need something like this, you have to add an own finisher that does the upload stuff - see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForDevelopers/AddFinisherClasses/Index.html

Answer (score 2):

I have same problems in powermail and i use powermail `Finisher` class like below.

TYPOSCRIPT:

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup {
    finishers {
        1 {
          class = Vendor\Ext\Finisher\AddImageFinisher
          config {
             # set pid.            
             pid = TEXT
             pid.value = 79 // Here

             #set powermail fields title
             field_name = Name
             field_place = Place
             field_email = E-Mail
             field_message = Message
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Please reffere this link. [AddImageFinisher Class file](https://github.com/drc-systems/Powermail-save-image-third-party-table/blob/master/AddImageFinisher.php)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record. TYPO3 8 core ships a new form extension which allows both. With the save to database finisher you can easily edit fe_user data. Furthermore, all image uploads are handled as FAL. We will document this use case and release a small extension which does the job (soon).

Comment: that sounds great - please post here when you have done this, would love to take a look. thanks